# Boton Toogle para Filtros en Angular

Tags: angularjs, filtro, tabla-dinámica

estoy usando Angular para crear una tabla y filtrar algunas de sus columnas, tengo dos botones "accepted" y "declined", ambos realizan el filtro correcto, ahora estaba tratando de generar un comportamiento de toggle en cada uno de los botones, es decir, cuando hago click en uno de ellos y me hace el filtro correcto, al volver a clickearlo quisiera que me mostraran todos los resultados de la tabla original. No lo estoy logrando, como sería el camino correcto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[MI CODIGO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ttand-jqgecv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-flex-example.ts)